# PySpark RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a pyspark script and encountered an error below. It seems saying "RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration" due to my code "if len(rdd.take(1)) > 0:". I'm not sure if that's the real reason and wonder what exactly went wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

> ```
> 17/03/23 21:54:17 INFO DStreamGraph: Updated checkpoint data for time 1490320070000 ms
> 17/03/23 21:54:17 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1490320072000 ms.0 from job set of time 1490320072000 ms
> 17/03/23 21:54:17 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1490320072000 ms.1 from job set of time 1490320072000 ms
> 17/03/23 21:54:17 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1490320072000 ms.0
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py",
> ```
>
> line 65, in call
>           r = self.func(t, *rdds)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py",
>   line 159, in 
>           func = lambda t, rdd: old_func(rdd)
>         File "/home/richard/Documents/spark_code/with_kafka/./mongo_kafka_spark_script.py",
>   line 96, in _compute_glb_max
>           if len(rdd.take(1)) > 0:
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1343, in take
>           res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 965, in runJob
>           port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2439, in _jrdd
>           self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2372, in _wrap_function
>           pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2363, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
>           broadcast_vars = [x._jbroadcast for x in sc._pickled_broadcast_vars]
>       RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
>
> ```
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
>   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/richard/Documents/spark_code/with_kafka/./mongo_kafka_spark_script.py",
> ```
>
> line 224, in 
>           ssc.awaitTermination();
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py",
>   line 206, in awaitTermination
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63,
>   in deco
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line
>   319, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.awaitTermination.
>       : org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py",
>   line 65, in call
>           r = self.func(t, *rdds)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py",
>   line 159, in 
>           func = lambda t, rdd: old_func(rdd)
>         File "/home/richard/Documents/spark_code/with_kafka/./mongo_kafka_spark_script.py",
>   line 96, in _compute_glb_max
>           if len(rdd.take(1)) > 0:
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1343, in take
>           res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 965, in runJob
>           port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2439, in _jrdd
>           self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2372, in _wrap_function
>           pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
>         File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2363, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
>           broadcast_vars = [x._jbroadcast for x in sc._pickled_broadcast_vars]
>       RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
>
> ```
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
>   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: I changed that part of code to "if not rdd.isEmpty():" and got the same error.

Comment: `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration` means that you are working on a object of type `set` and it has changed size whilst you're manipulating it (or working with it however you may be). This throws an error because sets are immutable. Hopefully you can generalize off of this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846719/recursion-how-to-avoid-python-set-changed-set-during-iteration-runtimeerror

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

It seems not to be the best practice creating broadcast variables among iterations. Always use updateStateByKey if possible when stateful data is required.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if rdd.count() <1 :
```

take() can give exceptions, but, if more details were available we could have pinpointed the error.

Comment: are you sure about that?